# Monitoring memory usage of a process launched with subprocess.run() using memory_profiler python

Tags: python, memory, subprocess

I'm trying to monitor the memory usage of a process that I launch using the **`subprocess.run()`** function in Python. To achieve this, I'd like to use the `memory_profiler` package to get insights into the memory consumption of the subprocess as it executes.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import subprocess
from memory_profiler import memory_usage

def run_subprocess():
    subprocess.run("g++ -Wall -o test.out code.cpp".split(), check=True)
    subprocess.run(["./test.out"], stdin=open("input.txt", 'r'), stdout=open("output.txt", 'w'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mem_usage = memory_usage((run_subprocess, (), {}))
    max_mem = max(mem_usage)
    print(mem_usage)
    print("Max memory usage:", max_mem, "MB")
```

**Output:**

```
[19.8515625, 19.953125, 19.953125, 19.953125, 19.953125, 19.953125, 19.953125, 19.953125, 19.953125, 19.96484375]
Max memory usage: 19.96484375 MB
```

However, I've noticed that the memory usage reported by memory_profiler doesn't seem to change as the subprocess runs. I know that the memory usage doesn't increase because the function `run()` are not allocating any new memory.

What steps do I need to take to properly monitor the memory usage of a process launched with subprocess.run() using memory_profiler? Are there any additional considerations or modifications needed in my code?

Any help or guidance on how to achieve accurate memory monitoring in this subprocess scenario would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should be providing the PID of the child processes, otherwise it is just capturing the memory usage of the current process, which isn't doing much based on the code you showed

Comment: @gold_cy Do you mean providing the PID to the `memory_profiler` module?